# d3.js water chart bug

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have derived a water chart - that used use circle gauges - into rectangle bars  but the clipping path is not taking on the full height of the chart.

//Issues

```
1. The axis text does not wrap cleanly -- I need it to do so to make it legible.
2. The rectangle is more of a square -- it needs to be more "bar chart" like - consume more vertical space but render correctly.
```

-- the difference between these two jsfiddles is just the config1.fillShape parameter. -- rect/circle

// broken bar version

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/132/

// working old round gauge version

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/133/

the core functions for the clip area -- clipArea and drawShapeWave

clipArea function

```
  // The clipping wave area.
  const clipArea = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) {
      return waveScaleX(d.x);
    })
    .y0(function(d) {
      return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * config.waveOffset * -1 + Math.PI * 2 * (1 - config.waveCount) + d.y * 2 * Math.PI));
    });

  if (config.fillShape == "circle") {
    clipArea
      .y1(function(d) {
        return (fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight);
      });
  } else {
    clipArea
      .y1(function(d) {
        return (fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight);
      });
    //.y1(function(d) { return (config.height - (fillCircleRadius * 2) + waveHeight); } );
  }
```

and the drawShape

```
  var drawShapeWave = function(shape) {
    // Draw the wave shape.

    if (shape == "circle") {
      fillGroup.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", radius)
        .attr("cy", radius)
        .attr("r", fillCircleRadius);
    } else {
      fillGroup.append("rect")
        .attr("x", radius - fillCircleRadius)
        .attr("y", radius - fillCircleRadius)
        .attr("width", fillCircleRadius * 2)
        .attr("height", fillCircleRadius * 2)
        //.attr("height", config.height - (fillCircleRadius * 2));
    }

    fillGroup
      .style("fill", config.waveStartColor)
      .transition()
      .duration(config.waveColorDuration)
      .style("fill", config.waveColor);
  }
```

//maybe this code sample has a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1860/

---

update

I've stripped out some code to leave just the square water chart itself

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/141/

---

I've create a version where the radius is half the height - right at the top - and so its created a giant square - that just gets clipped - but this isn't very clean - and its still a bit aloof on controlling the clipping path properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/145/

---

Update 2 -- 12/09/2017

I've placed the container and the wave in separate g elements -- it seems stable from width 70 to 90 -- but beyond that it starts to break .. if you can decipher what is going wrong -- provide a well documented answer - bounty is yours.

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/165

Comment: That's because you're basically using the radius for the width and height of the gauge. Since your gauge is rectangular, the width and height are different so you need to get and set them separately instead of using `fillCircleRadius`.

Comment: @Terry - that is the problem in a gist -- you think you have a solution as to how to separate that accordingly -- on which various parts -- I did try and place conditionals to take on different values if rect -- but it just produced unstable results?

Comment: Well... to be honest, your code is way too long to go through, and I don't really know where to even start.

Comment: @Terry - I have the same problem. I tried to make the code as dry as possible - and isolated the various functions - but I am not sure what is affecting the height of the clip wave - or the scales properly to tweak the code

Comment: - Maybe it would be easier to make it a giant square -- and just clip the sides

Comment: I have been testing, if you debug it with Chrome console and edit height="52.5" to for example height="100" or 200, it works, so, you need to know where the 52.5 comes from.

Comment: -- no its not as simple as just tweaking the height -- as that bar a) isn't snapped to the bottom - and b) doesn't represent 28% --- even if the height of the rect was 180 - that would be a start and fit with the padding around it -- to adjust the height on that rect -- "fillGroup.append("rect")" .attr("height", config.height - 20);

Comment: but you see -- its a case of adjusting the size of the rect, the clipping wave etc..

Comment: have a look in def> clippath id ="clipwaveliquid__xx" -- at the transform - set the y to like 127..    waveGroup.attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(0)+')')

Comment: so like the waveRiseScale has to be played with to get a higher value of y? --  const waveRiseScale = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([(fillCircleMargin+fillCircleRadius*2+waveHeight),(fillCircleMargin-waveHeight)])
          .domain([0,1]);

Comment: @Terry -- see if anything here helps -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1860/           var waveHeight = (config.h / 2) * waveHeightScale(fillPercent * 100);  and        var waveScaleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0, waveHeight]).domain([0, 1]);
   and  fillGroup.attr("height", config.h)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/142/

Comment: @Terry - I've got this variant going -- a giant square essentially - but I still don't follow how to just make the clipping path a rectangle -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/145/

Comment: -- any suggestions,,, bounty awaits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your clipping path a rectangle in the latest variant ( jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/145) by using the same values from config as your rectangle:

```
fillGroup.append("rect")
    .attr("x", config.width-5)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", config.width)
    .attr("height", config.height)
```

To add a margin for the clip-path (so the clip path has a smaller area), add a value to x,y,width, and height:

```
fillGroup.append("rect")
    .attr("x", config.width - 5 + config.margin)
    .attr("y", config.margin)
    .attr("width", config.width - 2 * config.margin)
    .attr("height", config.height - 2 * config.margin)
```

hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Not sure this works - its not rendering any wave now --  http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/147/  - @JusMalcolm

Comment: ah this version works based off 145 -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/148/  @JusMalcolm

Comment: -- may have resolve the issue -- very good man -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/151/

Comment: -- with the radius thing -- for a rectangle - I suppose it would be best to PICK radius on the max of height or width -- like if the rect was WIDE - like a swimming pool

Comment: "<clipPath id="clipWaveliquid_xx" transform="translate(25.5, -2#49.4687957763672)">"  -- this swimming pool seems busted -- how would you be able to stable a rect clipping shape -  http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/152/

Comment: Are you able to stabilize the code so the rect shape is correctly placed when the dimensions change? --- I've got a bigger jug here -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/154/   -- bigger jug -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/155/  and swimming pool example -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/156/ -- jarring cylinder example http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/157/

Comment: Its got a jarring bug at different sized containers -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151792/d3-liquid-chart-bugs-clipping-path-jarring @JusMalcolm

Comment: -- I've placed the container and the wave in separate g elements -- it seems stable from width 70 to 90 -- but beyond that it starts to break .. http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/165/

Comment: hey @Rob i'll check it out

Comment: a new bounty to fix it.

Comment: Another bug @JusMalcolm  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249138/d3-water-chart-height-bug-animating-shunt-up-when-the-value-peaks-above-90

Comment: ah this bug is annoying I can't see what's the problem @JusMalcolm

Comment: I got two bugs -- the water chart when it goes above a value of 90 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249138/d3-water-chart-height-bug-animating-shunt-up-when-the-value-peaks-above-90 and this brush on a d3v4 timeline chart https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304074/d3-js-timeline-upgrade-to-v4-brush-bugs

Comment: I'm not able to resolve this bug @JusMalcolm - its as if the waveheight is not properly set -- like there needs to be a -2*margin or something somewhere.