# d3 liquid chart bugs - clipping path jarring

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to stabilize this d3js liquid rectangle shape code. I am testing it with different dimensions but the configuration isn't holding - like its always being displaced.

-- this variant has a switch between a rect/circle gauge
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/132/

this tweak has configured the clipping path accordingly

```
fillGroup.append("rect")
    .attr("x", config.width - 5 + config.margin)
    .attr("y", config.margin)
    .attr("width", config.width - 2 * config.margin)
    .attr("height", config.height - 2 * config.margin)
```

// Jug 0

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/151/

[image]

// Jug 1

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/154

[image]

// Jug 2 - clipping starts to jump

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/155

[image]

// Jug 3 - clipping jump more obvious

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/156

[image]

Comment: -- I've placed the container and the wave in separate g elements -- it seems stable from width 70 to 90 -- but beyond that it starts to break .. http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/165/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 changes you need to make to stabilize this example ([jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/156](http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/156)):

1) set the `waveGroupXPosition` equal to `- config.width` or `- config.width/2`

2) change your `animateWave()` function to transition the path's transform attribute from `(0,0)` to `(config.width, 0)`. The function should look like this:

```
function animateWave() {
    wave.attr('transform','translate(0,0)');
    wave.transition()
        .duration(config.waveAnimateTime)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr('transform',`translate(${config.width},0)`)
        .on('end', animateWave);
}
```

you can view the updated version here: http://jsfiddle.net/xpb0hsey/

Comment: That's great @JusMalcolm  -- what was causing the jarring clipping bug -  the animate transform was wrong? -- It seems stable at different lengths now -- glass or swimming pool variants - is there any other way to improve the code base. -- Another issue I was having is getting the axisText at the bottom to wrap -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/132/

Comment: What was causing the clipping was that the translation transition was not always transitioning to an X value where the wave cycle is complete. I think this is because it was dependent on waveAnimateScale(), which depends on fillCircle/fillCircleMargin..etc which in the end might not produce a value for translate() that is a multiple of the width of a wave. 

Also, the waveXPosition was determining the offset of the waves, so it needed to be directly dependent on the path width/config width, so that when you transition the wave to 0 or to config.width it won't show a gap.

Comment: @Rob no I haven't heard of that site. Glad I could help

Comment: cheers man - stay tuned for more crazy experimental visualizations.

Comment: Yo @JusMalcolm -discovered a bug -- if they value is 90 its ok -- http://jsfiddle.net/xpb0hsey/1/ but above that number like 99 it botches -- the chart fills up and then shunts up -- http://jsfiddle.net/xpb0hsey/2/

Comment: -- here is an older chart that doesn't appear to have the problem -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/166/

Comment: problem here --     waveGroup.attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(fillPercent)+')');

Comment: another bug here for values higher than 90.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225849/d3-liquid-chart-bugs-height-shunting-bug

Comment: another bug here man --  values higher than 90  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225849/d3-liquid-chart-bugs-height-shunting-bug  @JusMalcolm